# How to split a string and select a specific field

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string which I need to split/slice up and set as different variables. Here is an example string:

```
Uploaded 09-09 2015, Size 2.05 GiB, ULed by USERX
```

I need the final output to be something like:

```
date = '09-09 2015' ; size = '2.05' ; user = 'USERX'
```

Here is the code I am using so far, with the variable 'string' representing the original string:

```
date, size, user = string.split(',')
date = date.split()[1], date.split()[2]
size = size.split()[1]
user = user.split()[2]
```

This works, but I can't help but feel that the code is painfully hacky. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks so much, may your code by elegant and error free.

Comment: Final regexp: `(?<=Uploaded\s)[\d\-\:\s]+|(?<=Size\s)[\d\.]+|(?<=ULed by\s)[^ ]+$` 
Based off of @Ajax1234's answer, but allows for special characters in the Username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = 'Uploaded 09-09 2015, Size 2.05 GiB, ULed by USERX'
results = re.findall('(?<=Uploaded\s)[\d\-\s]+|(?<=Size\s)[\d\.]+|(?<=ULed by\s)\w+$', s)
d = dict(zip(['date', 'size', 'user'], results))
```

Output:

```
{'date': '09-09 2015', 'size': '2.05', 'user': 'USERX'}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me a bit about the regular expression your using?

Answer (score 1):

Another one using a `mapping` dictionary:

```
import re

string = "Uploaded 09-09 2015, Size 2.05 GiB, ULed by USERX"
mappings = {'Uploaded': 'date', 'Size': 'size', 'by': 'user'}
rx = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*\b([-. A-Z0-9]{2,})\b')

result = {mappings[m.group(1)]: m.group(2).strip() 
          for m in rx.finditer(string)}
print(result)
```

This yields

```
{'date': '09-09 2015', 'size': '2.05', 'user': 'USERX'}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/R6Yka7/1).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try python's named group capturing:

```
import re
test_string = 'Uploaded 09-09 2015, Size 2.05 GiB, ULed by USERX'
p = re.compile(r'\w+ (?P<date>\d{2}-\d{2} \d{4}), Size (?P<size>\d+(\.\d+)?) GiB, ULed by (?P<user>\w+)')
result = p.search(test_string)
result.groupdict()
```